# How to check a value exists or not at the string end position in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, methods

Check String value existing or not useing string endwith methods

Answer (score 1):

**Javascript endsWith() method**

This method helps to check which sentence uses in a substring in the last position.

Note: The ends with the method is also case-sensitive

```js
const dialog = "I will must tech you who am i?"
console.log(dialog.endsWith("i?")) //true
console.log(dialog.endsWith("i")) //false
```